# Incorrectly Projected PostGIS data in TileMill

Tags: postgis, shapefile, coordinate-system, tilemill

When I bring `PostGIS` data in `EPSG:900913` into `TileMill`, my layers end up on other continents.

This is my workflow:

(1) Save `shapefiles` in `QGIS` to `EPSG:900913`

(2) Import the `shapefiles` using `PostGIS Shapefile and DBF loader 2.0` in `pgadminIII`
... specify SRID as `900913` in the loader

(3) Add `PostGIS` layer in `TileMill`... specify SRS as `900913`.

I get this result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztw2c03o9r7gv30/tileMill_projection.png

Some notes: I have no problems loading the `PostGIS` data into `QGIS` afterwards in the same projection (on-the-fly disabled). I have tried the same process using WGS84 `EPSG:4326` & WGS84 / Pseudo Mercator `EPSG:3857` with no luck.

My guesses are that either (1) the `Extent` parameters when Adding PostGIS Layer in `TileMill` have something to do with this (2) TileMill is not reading my PostGIS spatial_ref_sys table correctly. Any thoughts and/or suggestions?

I'm going to try inserting a new spatial_ref_sys table like [here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6627/).

Thanks again!

Comment: What is the original projection of the shapefiles before you save them out to `900913`?

Comment: EPSG:`26913` - NAD83 / UTM zone 13N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012723/how-to-change-srid-of-geometry-column#comment3079841_3013174), I searched for [this](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6627/) `spatial_ref_sys` table and inserted it into to my `PostGIS` database.

Reloaded the `shapefiles` into `PostGIS` in `ESPG: 900913`.

Restarted `TileMill`, added my `PostGIS` layers, and they are all layered correctly.